# Is it possible to add integer values while concatenating Strings?

Tags: java, string, sum, integer, concatenation

Consider the following code (excerpt of main method):

```java
String str = "The result: ";
int c = 5;
int k = 3;
System.out.println(str + c + k); // This would concatenate the all values, i.e. "The result: 53"
```

If the only thing allowed to be modified is within `System.out.println()`, is it possible to concatenate `str` to the sum of `k` and `c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
System.out.println(str + (c + k));
```

You can change order of execution by adding parentheses (same way as in math).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, as @talex said, you may use this single line code.
Yet, I think that this additude is a bit confusing, and may cause the code to be unreadable.

A better practice would be:

```
String str = "The result: ";
int c = 5;
int k = 3;
int result = c + k;
System.out.println(str + result);
```

This way, the code is more readable, and the order of execution will not confuse the programmers that read this code.

Comment: How is this a better practice? Having more lines of code is usually not 'better readable'. In such short snippets, sure, but this kind of code also occurs in not-so-small snippets.

Comment: Short code is not a good practice if it makes the code unreadable. Readability is one of the most important practices in the industry.

Comment: that is just assuming it'll be unreadable. System.out.println("The som is: " + (number1 + number2)); is very easy to read. If it's a print statement like this, many consider it easier to read than having to go over several lines of code.

Yes, readability is important, so is efficiency. You are creating a variable you don't need. If you do this here, chances are, you're doing it all over your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes
you should have use parentheses around sum of integers

```
System.out.println(str + (c + k));
```